# How do I get a list of duplicate fonts and their type (Type 1, TrueType, etc) in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, fonts

I'm trying to find duplicate fonts on a Windows 2008 machine. The tricky part is when you look in C:\Windows\Fonts that duplicate fonts may show up with different names. It is not until you double click on them and see the properties that the Typeface name is the same. We're having problems with fonts conflicting because we have a TrueType and a Type 1 installed at the same time.

I've tried the following:

```
InstalledFontCollection collection = new InstalledFontCollection();

foreach (var family in collection.Families)
{
    Console.WriteLine(family.Name);
}
```

But, that only gives the font family names and does not show individually installed font files. I couldn't find a way to get the font type from the InstalledFontCollection or a list of the fonts in the FontFamily.